# Custom method signature in a scala dsl

Tags: scala, dsl

Is there a way to create a scala dsl which enables me to write code similar to this pseudo-code

**edited: changed to scala pseudo code**

```
object AccessProtectedClass extends App{
   def protectedMethod(param:String)
     permit_if (param.startsWith("asdf") and RAM <= 10) : Int = {
         var result = 10
         //do something
         return result;
   } 
}
```

If the access is not granted due to the 'permit if' statement a exception should be thrown.
Which scala concepts do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, basically the `permit_if` method just takes a condition and a block of code, and throws an exception of the condition is not met.
This is trivially implemented as follows:

```
def permit_if[T]( condition: Boolean )( f: => T ): T = {
  if ( condition ) f
  else throw new Exception("Permit conditions not met!")
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
object AccessProtectedClass extends App{
   def protectedMethod( param:String ): Int = 
     permit_if (param.startsWith("asdf") && RAM <= 10)  {
         var result = 10
         //do something
         return result;
   } 
}
```

In fact the standard library already contains a method `require`  to check requirements, so unless you need to throw a very specific exception, you might just use that. Just replace `permit_if` with `require` in the above code snippet and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to write code similar to this. There are two things you have to keep in mind:

- Scala infix notation follows the pattern `obj method param method param method param...`, so you have to place keywords for method names at the proper places.
- Operator precedence can help you or hinder you. For example, `<=` has greater precedence than `and`, which will help with the snippet you've shown. So does dot notation. Parenthesis following an object also gets a higher precedence as the apply method on that object, which Specs2, for instance, puts to good use.

So, back to this:

```
permit if param.startsWith("xyz") and CPU <= 50 { ... }
```

We can break it like this:

```
permit // object
if     // method, though "if" is a reserved word, so you have to pick something else
param.startsWith("xyz") // param, because of higher precedence
and    // method
CPU <= 50 // param, because of higher precedence
// method needed here!
{ ... } // param
```

So it looks to me as if the builder pattern will work here, with minor adjustments. The parameter to `and` (or any `or`) will probably be by-name, so you can avoid evaluation of latter conditions if the result is defined by the former ones.

Answer (score -1):

Scala DSLs are valid Scala code. What you posted isn't. Therefore, it's not possible.